# Changing Android Spinner Background

Tags: android

I have an android spinner that has an arrow that points down.  When the list is open, I would like the arrow to point up.  There used to be a state_dropdown_showing.  In API 15 (4.0.3) this state seems to be removed.

What is the proper way to know if the list is open or not, such that the background of the spinner (including the arrow) could be changed dynamically via XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use separate ping for showing UP arrow
The first link is really useful , other links may give you some idea:

1. http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57

   [Android - Issue with custom Spinner background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993156/android-issue-with-custom-spinner-background)

   [Custom Spinner Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456334/android-custom-spinner-background)

   [Custom Spinner Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456334/android-custom-spinner-background)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My question should be more specific I guess.  I had no problem creating a custom background and arrow.  The problem is that I want the background to change when the list is open.  How do you tell if the list is open?  Android used to have a state_ for this but its been removed.  Why???

Comment: Just for folks reading this thread, I still have not found a good way and no examples for doing this.  I suppose you could put the adapter class in the view itself, and catch the onClick (view object) and onItemSelected (adapter class) and flip the background arrow.  The problem is still that if the user clicks elsewhere its essentially an abort and the list closes.  I have not found any event to catch that.